# How to open a screen after device unlocked on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way, using only Flutter, to detect when the device is unlocked? (password, faceid, fingerprint, doesn't matter)...

For example, when the device is unlocked, I would like to open a Page/Screen/Activity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is platform specific. On Android there's [USER_PRESENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) broadcast, sent when the user is present after device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone) which basically means exactly what you want.

Comment: Good. I will check it out. Any suggestion for iOS? I'm searching.